# Can a young teenager give authentic lectures about islam on youtube without a scholar degree?

Tags: halal-haram

Aoa my concern is that, i want to be a scholar but we do not have any guarantee about our lives. so can i start giving Islamic lectures on social media like explaining one authentic hadith and an authentic Islamic story.like a random discussion on hadith and stories.JazakAllah

Comment: Wasak ... out of curiosity, are you pursuing a course in fiqh or ilm? If not, how can you guarantee that your tafsir of the Hadith will be factual?

Comment: i will use the six authentic books for guideline and sometimes  a story told by a scholar in his lecture.can i do this if not your guidance will be helpful.

Comment: I'm not an expert in field but IMHO each time before making a video, go over your content with a scholar/imam. If they tell you it is as per the ijtihad of the ulema, then inshallah you will be closer to the facts. Best of Luck.

Comment: If he was instructed and his knowledge was tested (peer reviewed) by people of knowledge why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salam.
No, you can't. There are many requirements for that. I like your good intentions, but it is arrogant to think you could do that at such a young age. You don't have the knowledge. You don't have experience. You don't have the necessary skills. You are not mature enough to understand certain topics. And i can keep on going.

People who do this stuff are mostly people who have spend years of their life dedicated to knowledge. They often have traveled throughout the Muslim world and sometimes even beyond that, in order to increase their knowledge. Just look at Mufti Menk, Hamza Yusuf, Mufti Abu Layth, etc... Those are examples of known scholars who have traveled to many different countries, have had many teachers, and many years of experience to be able to comment on ahadeeth. If you humble yourself and become older and more mature you will understand that, in sha Allah.

Since you're a teenager: try to focus more on your studies. Your job is not to teach people. That's the job of a teacher. The teacher has reached a specific "rank or level", so to say, in order to be able to do that. To give lectures without a scholar degree is like designing a bridge without an engineering degree. Such a bridge would just collapse and potentially claim innocent lives. Just like it is the job of a car mechanic to repair cars, or the job of a baker to bake bread, it is your job as a student to study. Whatever your study may be. And if you want to be a good Muslim, don't obsess over Islam. This is a mistake many young Muslims make, including myself when i was a young teenager. Try to balance Islam in your life with your dunya. Islam is an easy religion.

Focus on your studies. Take your elders' advice. You know the classic advice.

Salam.

Comment: Jazakallah I understand.